# Add Tab bar below Status bar using Material iOS

Tags: ios, cosmicmind

How to add tabbar below navigation bar using the Material's pod by CosmicMind

I was able to achieve this but it was touching the status bar like this

[image]

I want this to be below the status bar.

Answer (score 2):

You can do with below code, add 20px `StatusBar` Height in `Top(20)`

```
fileprivate func prepareTabBar() {
    tabBar = TabBar()
    tabBar.delegate = self

    tabBar.dividerColor = Color.grey.lighten4
    tabBar.dividerAlignment = .bottom

    tabBar.lineColor = Color.indigo.base
    tabBar.lineAlignment = .bottom

    tabBar.backgroundColor = Color.grey.lighten3
    tabBar.buttons = buttons

    view.layout(tabBar).horizontally().top(20)
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can create custom class of Tabbar and change frame at top:

```
class CustomTabBarController: UITabBarController {

   @IBOutlet weak var myTabBarOutlet: UITabBar!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        UIApplication.shared.statusBarFrame.size.height
        myTabBarOutlet.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y:  myTabBarOutlet.frame.size.height, width: myTabBarOutlet.frame.size.width, height: myTabBarOutlet.frame.size.height)
    }
```